# How does the second wheel change the shutter speed in aperture-priority mode on my Nikon D90?

Tags: nikon, camera-controls, aperture-priority

When I am in aperture mode in my d90 camera, I have noticed I can also change my shutter speed by clicking the rear wheel.
Is that a bug? How is it possible?

If it is not a bug, how do I know the original shutter speed that my camera initially chose for that aperture ?

Comment: Welcome to the site, stam! There's no need to surround your for greetings — it's a Q/A site, so it's not rude to just jump right in and ask. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be changing the aperture in Shutter Priority mode (or the shutter speed in Aperture Priority mode) *indirectly* by actually changing the ISO. Look at custom menu setting d3 (Show ISO/Easy ISO) -- if that is turned on, the "unused" dial for your priority mode becomes the ISO dial -- you don't have to hit the ISO button to make a change.

Comment: I knew I should have read my manual, 2 books and other documentation better! Now, if only this would work in manual mode as its the only complaint I have with my D90. But that's what the 300s and higher models are for and look forward to my next purchase.

Comment: N-I-C-E !!!
Now this is the answer. Thanks a lot. 
Now that I got it - its pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

{My bad - probably a lack of sleep made me write the previous nonsense}

Update:

This is your way of doing Auto Exposure Compensation. You can tell what is the original (neutral) speed by looking at the AEC indicator on your camera. If the indicator is at 0, that this is the standard exposure. Otherwise, you are compensating.

Update 2:

When shooting in an auto or semi-auto mode (like the Aperture mode), the camera sets the 3 exposure parameters (Aperture, Speed, ISO) so as to get a "standard" amount of brightness in the metered area. In the semi-auto modes, you set one or two of the parameters, and the camera then calculates the 3rd.

Sometimes, the standard exposure (Auto Exposure) is not giving the right exposure to the scene. For example, when shooting snow, the AE will generate a dark (gray) image instead of bright white. You can then tell the camera to make your scene brighter and look like it was actually was. This is the AE Compensation, or AEC. This is done by means of overriding the automatically calculated value of the 2nd or 3rd parameter. In this case they are the speed and ISO.

I am not familiar with Nikon systems, but I assume you can tell the camera to fix the ISO at a constant value, then the speed is the only variable left.

Comment: Wait, (btw: thanks for the reply) . what is the AEC ? is there a way to lock it from being changed ? when I change the shutter speed, why is my exposure comensation still 0?

Comment: and why is the iso also changing when i rotate the wheel ?

Comment: BTW - welcome to the community.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the elaborate answer . but my question was different . Let me re-explain. I know that I can fix the expossure compansation using the +/- button and that will change my shutter speed. I think I did something different with my factory settings . cause now I can also move it by changing the shutter speed wheel . and then the AEC sign doesnt change and i dont know what was the original shutter speed was. now lets say i am stopping down after rotating the shutter wheel. Is the new  shutter compensated or not. I didnt do it through the AEC feature so is is not showing anywhere. 10x

Comment: @stam - If I understand correctly, then this is exactly the case where you change one of the 2 variables (the speed), and the camera recalculates the 3rd (ISO) so the exposure remain constant. Is it that the ISO is going up when the speed gets higher? The original speed is not so important as long as you have the exposure you want. Of course, you have side effects of more/less noise or motion blur.

Comment: mmm.. But this makes it no diffrerent than the manual mode. I like to shoot with A mode. and I compensate through -/+ button . then I always see what has changed. but when I compensate through the shutter speed wheel I dont see a what I compensated and how much.

Comment: @stam - that's b/c you are not compensating (the exposure, that is), you merely change the balance between the two free variables (to get a desired effect). It is actually very different from manual, where you have to manually set each of the variables. It is, however similar to the P or Auto modes (which is why it is called semi-auto mode).

Comment: Well, thanks again for your explanation . but if i am on aperture mode and ichoose the aperture is want and then i rotate the shutter wheel , and it lets me choose shutter mode then it is as if i am on m mode. no?

Comment: @stam - no, b/c the camera still changes the ISO accordingly. In M mode, all 3 parameters are set by the user.

Comment: Ok. you are tight about that. But I know that the camera determines the shutter speed by a certain algorithm (18% grey or something like that). and now i moved the shutter to be very fast. and now I set the apperture to a different value. and I still get a fast shutter. So I am back to my first practical question. how do i know what is the default value in the new aperture? I dont see any compensaqtion value other than 0. 10x for your time.

Comment: @stam - I believe that if you release the shutter button and depress it again (half press), the camera re-calculates the free exposure variables, this time with the new aperture value. Then, you'll see the default shutter speed.

Comment: nope. didnt work.

Comment: OK, let me understand the sequence of operations: 1. Set to A mode; 2. Set your aperture (say, 4.5); 3. Half-press, camera sets ISO 400 and Speed 1/1000; 4. Change speed using the "other" wheel (the one that does not change the exposure, whatever this is on a Nikon) so the speed changed to 1/500. You observe the ISO reduced to 200; 5. Change the Aperture to 3.5. You observe the same shutter of 1/500 but the ISO changed? 6. Now, you release the button and half-press it again (on the same exact subject) but the camera does not change the speed?

Comment: not exactly . 4) lets say I changed it to something more dramatically - 1/20. 5. change the aperture to 4.5 now it will be with shutter - 1/15. it keeps the delta. and drags it to the next aperture change.

Comment: @stam - I am not sure I understand your last comment, but is it possible that by going down to 1/20 you have hit the minimum ISO level and hence have an over exposure? Can yo please post actual steps and numbers that you see? Remember to aim at the same subject throughout the process. Describe what are the actions you take and what is the reading of the 3 parameters after each step.